# Azure Auth Token - AADSTS500113: No reply address is registered for the application

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-authentication

I am trying to obtain a token through postman using the following tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/access-fhir-postman-tutorial

I have successfully filled out the credentials then a pop up appears asking for my credentials. This then throws the following error:

[image: Sorry but we're having trouble signing you in]

Does anyone know why this error is occurring or how I can fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to your error message: no reply address is registered for the application. So, try to set the **callback url** for your application, usually the url is the reply address.

Go to **AAD**>**App registrations**>**your app**>**Authentication**

[image]

Please note that the reply url configured in the Azure portal needs to be the same as the url you used in postman.

Comment: Hi, I added the postman url to the redirects as you mentioned and it worked, thanks

Comment: What is the postman url you referred to?

Answer (score 10):

Another reason could be that you have n't added a web platform...

***[Step 1]*** Go to AAD>App registrations>your app>Authentication
***[Step 2]*** Click on Add a Platform

[image]

***[Step 3]*** Select Web

[image]

***[Step 4]*** Add Redirect URLs

[image]

***[Step 5]*** and click on "Configure" button

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The issue occurs because the redirect url set in Azure for the registered app did not match the one used in my web app. So check if there's a match for both URLs.

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue when trying to set up Active Directory login at work. I confirmed with my IT department many times that the redirectURI was configured correctly in Azure App Services

Turns out we needed to add login.microsoft.com to the allowed CORS list
After allowing that site the application worked as expected

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).